# Open websites in same window but different tabs

Tags: batch

How to change the batch script to open websites under same window but different tabs. I use below batch file.

```
@echo off
start iexplore www.bbc.com
ping /n 10 localhost>nul 2>&1
start iexplore www.cnn.com
```

Thank you in advance.

REVISION (workable)

```
start /d "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox" firefox.exe  www.bbc.com
start /d "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox" firefox.exe  www.cnn.com
```

Comment: [Similar question answered on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188850/how-to-launch-multiple-internet-explorer-windows-tabs-from-batch-file)

Comment: @SergiyTytarenko, Tks for your reference. I updated the workable script.